# Access to kubernetes service through localhost fails on Chrome

Tags: docker, google-chrome, kubernetes, localhost

I have been working through the Tutorial at [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/). Using localhost to access containerized application works fine when run as a standalone container. However, it fails as soon as I deploy it through Kuberbetes or Swarm.

Under Part 3 of the tutorial I successfully deploy to Kubernetes (using micro8s.kuberbetis)

```
kubectl apply -f bb.yaml
```

and I get

```
deployment.apps/bb-demo created
service/bb-entrypoint created
```

However, I cannot use Chrome to visit the application pages. Using localhost:30001 with Chrome, it says "Waiting on cache..." and then "Waiting on localhost..." forever.

I tried visting it through Firefox and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using localhost to access local pages in Chrome. It works fine as soon we switch to http://127.0.0.1:30001 or using the IP-address or name of the host computer, i.e. http://frodo:30001 in my case.